# How Can I Process SageMaker Ground Truth NER JSON Output into DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, feature-engineering, named-entity-recognition, aws, sagemaker

So, I've recently created a job using AWS SageMaker Ground Truth for NER purposes, and have received an output in the form a manifest file. I'm now trying to process the manifest file into a dataframe, and I'm failing greatly.

The JSON file is incredibly complex. Here's an example of it based on [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-output.html):

```
{
    "source": "Amazon SageMaker is a cloud machine-learning platform that was launched in November 2017. SageMaker enables developers to create, train, and deploy machine-learning (ML) models in the cloud. SageMaker also enables developers to deploy ML models on embedded systems and edge-devices",
    "ner-labeling-job-attribute-name": {
        "annotations": {
            "labels": [
                {
                    "label": "Date",
                    "shortDisplayName": "dt"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Verb",
                    "shortDisplayName": "vb"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Thing",
                    "shortDisplayName": "tng"
                },
                {
                    "label": "People",
                    "shortDisplayName": "ppl"
                }
            ],
            "entities": [
                {
                    "label": "Thing",
                    "startOffset": 22,
                    "endOffset": 53
                },
                {
                    "label": "Thing",
                    "startOffset": 269,
                    "endOffset": 281
                },
                {
                    "label": "Verb",
                    "startOffset": 63,
                    "endOffset": 71
                },
                {
                    "label": "Verb",
                    "startOffset": 228,
                    "endOffset": 234
                },
                {
                    "label": "Date",
                    "startOffset": 75,
                    "endOffset": 88
                },
                {
                    "label": "People",
                    "startOffset": 108,
                    "endOffset": 118
                },
                {
                    "label": "People",
                    "startOffset": 214,
                    "endOffset": 224
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "ner-labeling-job-attribute-name-metadata": {
        "job-name": "labeling-job/example-ner-labeling-job",
        "type": "groundtruth/text-span",
        "creation-date": "2020-10-29T00:40:39.398470",
        "human-annotated": "yes",
        "entities": [
            {
                "confidence": 0
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0
            },
            {
                "confidence": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So far, I've only been able to extract the `"source"` and the `"entities"`, but now the dataframe has a list of dictionaries on its second column.

How should I process the JSON file into a DataFrame using `Pandas`? Or is there a better way to process this output?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's what I'm hoping to see
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: When you say you want to convert the json file into a dataframe, what do want the resulting dataframe to look like?

Comment: Well, I want to have the source of the data on one column, and then the labels on several columns adjacent to it filled with the labelled words.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your explanation, could you add a table showing the expected output to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use base python syntax to transform the dictionary into a format that would work for `pandas` before converting it to a dataframe:

```
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd

entities = data["ner-labeling-job-attribute-name"]["annotations"]["entities"]
entities = [
    (entity["label"], data["source"][entity["startOffset"]:entity["endOffset"]])
    for entity in entities
]
entities = {
    key: [[x[1] for x in data]]
    for key, data in groupby(entities, lambda x: x[0])
}
df = pd.DataFrame({"Source": data["source"], **entities}).to_markdown(index=False)
```

| Source | Thing | Verb | Date | People |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon SageMaker is a cloud machine-learning platform that was launched in November 2017. SageMaker enables developers to create, train, and deploy machine-learning (ML) models in the cloud. SageMaker also enables developers to deploy ML models on embedded systems and edge-devices | ['cloud machine-learning platform', 'edge-devices'] | ['launched', 'deploy'] | ['November 2017'] | ['developers', 'developers'] |

Comment: Wow, this might be the one I'm looking for.